# Aumentar línea subrayado de un enlace en CSS

Tags: html, css, html5

quiero aumentar la longitud de los subrayados de los enlaces, os enseño el código y lo que quiero conseguir:

```
.a-footer{
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
padding-bottom: 10px;
```

}

Según lo tengo me aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el resultado que quiero sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé muy bien cómo hacerlo... Si me echaran una mano, se lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias!!

Edit: Agrego el HTML

```
<footer>

    <div class="container footer-1 row align-items-center">
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Supermercados</a>
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Folletos</a>
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Otros Servicios</a>
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Redes Sociales</a>
    </div>
```

Las reglas son estas:

```
.container{
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
```

}

```
.footer-1{
background-color: rgb(41, 123, 60);
height: 10vh;
```

}

La de row y align-items-center es simplemente para flex

Comment: Agrega el HTML del asunto

Comment: Ya está todo! Gracias

Comment: Prueba definir un `width` en tus elementos `a-footer`

Comment: Tan fácil que era. y juraría que probé con width anteriormente... qué rabia! Muchas gracias compa

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto.

En este código, el pseudo-elemento ::after crea un subrayado debajo de cada enlace. Puedes ajustar la propiedad width para cambiar la longitud del subrayado.

```css
.container{
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.footer-1{
  background-color: rgb(41, 123, 60);
  height: 10vh;
}

.a-footer {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.a-footer::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<footer>

    <div class="container footer-1 row align-items-center">
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Supermercados</a>
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Folletos</a>
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Otros Servicios</a>
        <a href="#" class="a-footer">Redes Sociales</a>
    </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Gracias compa. Con aumentar el width en .a-footer es suficiente

Comment: @oli699 pon entonces como respuesta qué has hecho finalmente. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido útil.

Comment: Okey, pero no me deja hasta que pasen 22 horas

Answer (score 0):

Bastaba con añadir width a la regla .a-footer

```
.a-footer{
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
padding-bottom: 10px; 
margin-right: 80px;
width: 50%;
}
```

En este caso al crear una regla para esos enlaces lo que he hice fue quitarle el subrayado de serie de los enlaces y ponerle uno con border-bottom y con padding bottom bajarlo a la altura que lo quería. Y ya luego con width aumento esa longitud, que no grosor. Si quieres más grosor lo añades en border-bottom

Comment: por que un width ???

Comment: Pues en este caso al crear una regla para esos enlaces lo que he hice fue quitarle el subrayado de serie de los enlaces y ponerle uno con border-bottom y con padding bottom bajarlo a la altura que lo quería. Y ya luego con width aumento esa longitud, que no grosor. Si quieres más grosor lo añades en border-bottom. Actualizo mi respuesta y a ver si te sirve

Comment: bueno trata de colocar todo los argumentos de tu respuesta en la respuesta junto al codigo, no esperes a que te vengan a preguntar...

Comment: Soy nuevo en el foro y voy con el tiempo justo la verdad. Lo siento, me iré haciendo, pero también hay formas de decir las cosas!!

Comment: y por que eres nuevo es que te tratan de orientar en como usar el sitio.

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias!